# Android CardFlip Animation not working

Tags: java, android, animation, android-fragments

I am experimenting with some Animations with Android. Basically I have this Activity that displays data from an API. Now when the user wishes to refresh that data, the Front card so to speak of which contains the data, flips to the Back card which is a loading animation. The process of loading new data kicks off and when it finishes the method that flips the so to speak of cards is called so the data can be revealed.

With my intentions in place I have everything explained above 99% complete. When I have the data from the API back in the UI thread controlling the cards, I am ready to update those interface objects that are part of the front card.

But setting the text of a TextView no longer works, and I'll explain that. When the front card gets switched out, the back card comes to the foreground, but when it comes time for the front card to come back with new data, it comes back with its default XML values. I can set TextViews all day of this front card but it return blank.

Code is below, please keep in mind I like to reverse engineer things like this. So some code I do not understand, it the sample from the Google Android development guide.

Here I set up some kind of fragment manager in the onCreate method of the Activity.
mShowingBack is a boolean for if the back card is the card in the foreground.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // If there is no saved instance state, add a fragment representing the
        // front of the card to this activity. If there is saved instance state,
        // this fragment will have already been added to the activity.
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment())
                .commit();
    } else {
        mShowingBack = (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);
    }

    // Monitor back stack changes to ensure the action bar shows the appropriate
    // button (either "photo" or "info").
    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
```

Even if I do not update the textviews with the new data, the front card is still bare and empty. Below is the method that flips the the two cards:

```
public void onClickFlipCard(View view) {

    if (mShowingBack) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        return;
    }

    // Flip to the back.

    mShowingBack = true;

    // Create and commit a new fragment transaction that adds the fragment for the back of
    // the card, uses custom animations, and is part of the fragment manager's back stack.

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()

            // Replace the default fragment animations with animator resources representing
            // rotations when switching to the back of the card, as well as animator
            // resources representing rotations when flipping back to the front (e.g. when
            // the system Back button is pressed).
            .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)

            // Replace any fragments currently in the container view with a fragment
            // representing the next page (indicated by the just-incremented currentPage
            // variable).
            .replace(R.id.container, new CardBackFragment())

            // Add this transaction to the back stack, allowing users to press Back
            // to get to the front of the card.
            .addToBackStack(null)

            // Commit the transaction.
            .commit();

}
```

When that method is called, even though it is not included the method call for retrieving the new data kicks off. I am not for sure if like creates a new instance of the card layout so when I try to modify it, I am not actually in touch with it or something?

When I get the data for example all I do is use the textview object used before the data load to set the new data:

```
textview_example.setText("Example, but nothing appears...")
```

Even further, when I call the textviews getText method, it returns text but none is shown...Any help would be great. If it matters here are the two fragment classes that represent the two cards,(The front where data is displayed and the back where a loading animation is shown).

Front Card Fragment:

```
public class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment {

public CardFrontFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_front, container, false);
}
}
```

Back Card Fragment

```
public class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {
public CardBackFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_back, container, false);
}
}
```

Here is also a link to the Android guide that I follow...
Animation works but afterward as I said I can not edit any of the properties of interface objects. Thanks!

Link: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html